# SVN Checkout into existing project folder

Tags: eclipse, svn, svn-checkout

I am trying to checkout the existing project folder into SVN repository but it is giving me such error:

Destination project is detached from the source control. So please take into consideration that the plug-in won't provide any SVN actions for these resources.

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

This is not the operation you are looking for. You should be using `import`.